# Selenium Python Bot not saving complete Array while scraping

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape around 4500K profiles from a website,

So I have taken an approach of first getting through & saving all the links of all profiles via a search result and saving all the profile links in an array and later visiting each profile links one by one to get the details.

Issue I am facing is although my BOT goes through complete the search results,

But the BOT saves only initial links around 70 80 in the array , So when it starts visiting the links from the array it only scraps initial 70 80 profile links and then keeps on repeating these same profile again & again.

If there any cache memory constraint which is not allowing the BOT to save other links or can anyone please guide me a BIT ahead on the same and enlighten.

Comment: The code is Below for your reference,

Comment: Where's the code? can you also share that website for better understanding?